# Problemas de conexion con mi bd (en contenedor) y el springboot

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, spring-boot, docker, backend

**Buenas, estoy tratando de dockerizar un proyecto, ya pude la bd y el front pero el backend no, la cuestion es que funciona bien con la bd, ahi muestro el aplication.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hps_cartuchos
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
server.port=${port:8082}
```

funciona bien pero cuando realizo la dockerizacion del backend, a la hora de ejecutar la imagen creada a partir del backend salta "refused conection" lo trate cambiando el spring.datasource.url, poniendole asi:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://1172.18.2.0:3306/hps_cartuchos
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
server.port=${port:8082}
```

tambien asi:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqlContenedor:3306/hps_cartuchos
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
server.port=${port:8082}
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutar el mvn clean install para poder crear el jar me salta error por el mal llamado de la base de datos en el aplication
Trate descargando dependencias, cambiando de distintas formas el dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:21
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8083
ADD target/backendCartuchos-1-docker.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

O simplemente ya alterando el aplication despues de crear la imagen del backend pero con todo esos metodos me salta el problema de conexion, ya no se que hacer, desde ya le agradezco por sus comentarios (estoy trabajando en la ide Intellij IDEA).

Comment: Hay una errata en la dirección IP: `1172.18.2.0:3306`, supongo que sobre el primer 1

Comment: Gracias por responder, de igual forma me sigue saliendo el mismo error